# Print line with this substring only once python

Tags: python, regex, string

I have a problem. I have a text file with lots of strings.
I want to search only for those with my substring in it.
But it gives me all possible matches.
My code is:

```
name = 'ok'
with open('C:/Users/Desktop/text.txt','r') as fin:
        for line in fin:
            if name in line:
                print line
```

it prints:

```
ok1.0 = 259
ok1.1 = 259
ok1.2 = 259
ok2.0 = 260
ok2.1 = 260
ok2.2 = 260
ok3.0 = 261
ok3.1 = 261
ok3.2 = 261
```

That is fine - it finds all the lines needed. But I don't need 3 lines with the same number at the end. How can I get only the lines with unique numbers at the end of the line? What can I do to get output like this?

```
ok1.0 = 259
ok2.0 = 260
ok3.0 = 261
```

I cannot search for regular expression like ok[0-9].0 <- this is not permitted. I have to find only lines with unique numbers at the end like above.
Thanks

Comment: What do you mean not permitted? And are you sure that the file doesn't contain duplicate lines?

Comment: you have all strings with  digits at end in it?

Comment: @e4c5 not permitted, because I cannot do that. I know that's the easiest way but in my case I have to figure out how to get unique numbers at the end of each line. This file doesn't contain duplicates

Comment: @Kaushal28 yes all strings have digits at the end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should in a way or another use a [`set()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set) of seen values (the numbers) to filter out future instances. Given that your file is sorted and every line is in the format of `tag = value`:

```
name = 'ok'
seen = set()
with open('C:/Users/Desktop/text.txt','r') as fin:
    for line in fin:
        # Split stripped line to a tag and a value
        tag, value = line.strip().split(' = ', 1)
        if name in tag and value not in seen:
            seen.add(value)
            print line
```

will print only the first matching lines.